# How do you Show/Hide Rows based on another cell? (Google Apps Script/Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hide, show-hide, show

**Goal:** Click a button/select an option to hide/reveal a number of rows. Example, click/select on cell A4 that hides rows A5-A8 and another A45 that hides rows A46-A59. A button would be preferred but I'll take whatever. Bonus points if I can use a custom image.

I have a function that hides rows but it only works sometimes, could be slow (takes anywhere from 5s or 20s+, although I have 900 rows) or sometimes only hides some of the list regardless of length. I copied the function from somewhere else and I probably didn't implemented it in the best way, which might explain some problems, but here's how it works.

On B8 there's a dropdown list (data validation, list of items). There are two options, one is a blank (technically an inivisible character) and the other is "H". In column C, I copy this code in the specific cells I want to hide:

```
=IF(B8="H","Hide","Show")
```

And here is the script:

```
/** HideRow */
function onEdit()
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for( i=1 ; i<=lastRow ; i++) { // i <= lastRow

    var status = sheet.getRange("C"+i).getValue();  // C = the column that writes Show/Hide

    if (status == "Hide") {                                           // status == "Hide" 
         sheet.hideRows(i);
       } 
    if (status == "Show"){                                           // status == "Show" 
     sheet.showRows(i); 
    }
   }
}
```

I will be adding more rows over time and I don't know if the script keeps track of the cell when it moves, which is why I wrote a line of code in individual cells (maybe an array would fix slowdown due to redundancy?). Although if it works better in the script than by all means do it. Would a named range be useful in this case?

I've looked at some others and haven't had luck, mostly because other than the variables I'm not sure what else I would need to change.

Answer (score 1):

**The onSelectionChange Trigger**

You just have to make new selection and select either A4 or A45 and this will toggle the visibility of the specified rows.  The point is that if you are already on one of the cells and you select it again that doesn't work there has to be a change in the selected range.

The good new is that you don't need any buttons or check boxes.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const C=['A4','A45'];//trigger ranges
  const R=[{row:5,count:4},{row:46,count:14}];//hide/show ranges with row and count for each
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const idx=C.indexOf(e.range.getA1Notation());
  if(idx!=-1) {
    //e.source.toast('idx= ' + idx);
    if(sh.isRowHiddenByUser(R[idx].row)) {
      sh.showRows(R[idx].row,R[idx].count);
    }else{
      sh.hideRows(R[idx].row,R[idx].count);      
    }
  }
}
```

This version uses the trigger strings ~1~ and ~2~ and works with a relative offset of 1 row which is configurable

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const T=['~1~','~2~'];
  const R=[{row:0,offset:1,count:4},{row:0,offset:1,count:14}];
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const idx=T.indexOf(e.range.getValue());
  R[idx].row=e.range.getRow()+R[idx].offset
  if(idx!=-1) {
    //e.source.toast('idx= ' + idx);
    if(sh.isRowHiddenByUser(R[idx].row)) {
      sh.showRows(R[idx].row,R[idx].count);
    }else{
      sh.hideRows(R[idx].row,R[idx].count);      
    }
  }
}
```

another version:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const obj={T:[],R:[new shrows(1,5,'~1~'),new shrows(1,5,'~2~'),new shrows(1,5,'~3~'),new shrows(1,5,'~4~')]};
  obj.R.forEach(function(e,i){obj.T.push(e.tstring)});
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const idx=obj.T.indexOf(e.range.getValue());
  obj.R[idx].row=e.range.getRow()+obj.R[idx].offset
  if(idx!=-1) {
    //e.source.toast('idx= ' + idx);
    if(sh.isRowHiddenByUser(obj.R[idx].row)) {
      sh.showRows(obj.R[idx].row,obj.R[idx].count);
    }else{
      sh.hideRows(obj.R[idx].row,obj.R[idx].count);      
    }
  }
}

function shrows(offset,count,tstring) {
  this.offset=offset;
  this.count=count;
  this.tstring=tstring;
  this.row=0;
}
```

The bad news about this trigger is that there doesn't appear to be a installable version yet so you can't perform operations that require permission.

[onSelectionChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: So it does work... but one last problem.

If I add a new row above A4, that would push it down to A5. Meaning I have to update the value in the script to A5 for it to work. I have a number of these dropdowns and based on what info I have to plug in, will likely add new rows everywhere, not just to the bottom.

Is there a way for it to retain the original position regardless? That's partly why I wrote had it look for a trigger word. Although maybe that's why it was slow and yours is quick (looking through the whole column rather than specific cells).

Comment: What do mean by it?

Comment: We could check for values on each selection change and trigger off of unique values.  What kinds of values are you considering?

Comment: Will the rows that you wish to hide always be a fixed offset from the cell with the trigger string?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. The amount that each dropdown hides will be the same (ex. A4 hides 4 rows, while A45 hides 14 rows, etc).

Comment: I tried the new update but it doesn't work as well as your first option (also it didn't unhide them for some reason). I think I'll just use the first one and write comments in the script saying what each cell represents to make editing it easier when I add new rows.

Comment: Perhaps you using the wrong trigger strings it's a tilde followed  by 1 followed by a tilde.  And there are two of them ~1~ and ~2~ .  ~1~ is the upper one and ~2~ is the lower one

Comment: The only problem I've seen with them is when thy are move so as they overlap.

Comment: I tested it out some more. It does reveal, but sometimes it works on its own, sometimes if I double click on it and press enter again it will respond quickly (if I typed it rather than when it's controlled by the drop down).

I would've had to adjust the variables for either anyway so I'll just go with the first. But thanks so much for you help! You gave me an option that works well.

Comment: I just saw this. Do you know how to do this? It looks much simpler but I couldn't find any info on what it's called or how to do it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKtLN.gif

Comment: Those are groups. [Class Group](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group)

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try using this with Named Ranges.

Comment: Wow Class Groups were exactly what I was looking for!